# image metadata, Can I add custom fields or comments?

Tags: django, image, image-processing

I am a bit lost on what to do here. I have a django app that will be using a lot of images and I want to keep track of the source of all these images.

I had it setup to have a model that has two fields (`FilePath` and `Char`) that I would use to store the image path and the source, but now I am thinking that is a waste of energy. I would like to store the source right with the image.

What would be the best way to go about this?

(possibility) I see in my OSX finder that there is something called comments, can these be accessed across all machines or is this OSX specific?

Comment: wataminute what you want to store ? "source" ? Django file object have lot attribute please read the document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/file/

Comment: @RajaSimon I have read through the docs, and I don't think that answers my question in any way. I want to keep some arbitrary text of my choosing with the file. Is there a way to do this with metadata on the file itself?

Comment: No. Where would that data go? Data goes in the database; if you need to store new bits of data, you need new fields for it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be definitely no. I will have to be adding another model field to store this information